# What is the largest Lego kit commercially available?

Tags: records, sets

I believe the Imperial Star Destroyer is the biggest in terms of size, at 58.8 cm by 50.5 cm by 21 cm, and the Death Star in the number of pieces, at 3803. Are there any newer, bigger models?

Comment: I can't wait to see when the answer to this question will change.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In 2008, LEGO released an exclusive Creator model of the [Taj Mahal](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=10189-1), with **5922 pieces**, the most in a commercial LEGO set.

[image: Picture of the Taj Mahal]

It is no longer available at the LEGO Shop, but it's still commercially available from other retailers. [Here's its Amazon product page.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002EEP3NY)

Comment: Woah. That's quite a kit. Like to see the average build time for that.

Comment: Average time I don't know, but the [record](http://www.recordholders.org/en/list/lego.html) is 1 hour 47 minutes and 9 seconds for a team of 6 persons.

Comment: Any other place besides amazon where i can buy this set for a lesser price? I remember when it was launched, it was sold for $250. Not sure why they stopped manufacturing this and why the prices sky rocketed. Also, is it still worth spending $1k for such a architecture.

Comment: This answer has became outdated, the most up-to-date list is currently found at [Brickset](https://brickset.com/sets/query-45).

Answer (score 8):

The [Super Star Destroyer](http://shop.lego.com/en-GB/Super-Star-Destroyer-10221), with 3152 pieces, is nearly 50 inches (124.5 cm) long and weighs nearly 8 pounds (3.5kg):

[image: Super Star Destroyer]

While the [Ultimate Collectors Edition Millennium Falcon](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=10179-1) had over 5000 pieces, and was 33" long, 22" wide and 8" tall! (84cm long x 56cm wide x 21cm tall), and was officially advertised as the biggest set ever made - it was almost exactly to Mini Figure scale as well.

[image: Ultimate Collectors Edition Millennium Falcon - from Brickset.com]

Answer (score 7):

In terms of height, I think the [Eiffel Tower](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=10181-1) is unmatched, standing at 1 meter tall on a base of 50x50cm. When looking at the picture below, keep in mind a cat can easily pass under the arches:

[image: 10181 — Eiffel Tower]

The parts count, at 3428, isn't too bad either.

Comment: I'm not sure a cat will be any more interested in passing under its arches than using it as a scratching post though ;)

Comment: Ok, maybe not so much passing under than deciding it's a funny place to take a nap.

Comment: This set is almost impossible to move.  You have to have a board and steady arms.

Comment: @LarsTech it's not that bad, actually, as the three sections are separable.There are only 4 connecting studs between each section, the rest are tiles.

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not pay attention to the laws of gravity the first time I tried to move it.  It did not end well.  :-(

Answer (score 2):

The set with the most pieces as of 2018 is the [**#75192 Millennium Falcon**](https://brickset.com/sets/75192-1/Millennium-Falcon) with 7541 pieces.

[image]

It measures over 8” (21cm) high, 33” (84cm) long and 22” (56cm) wide.

Comment: Think it might be worth converting my answer to a wiki and keeping it up to date since it's the pinned answer?