# Is there a web service showing me the LEGO set with the most parts?

Tags: set-database

I'm interested in a challenge building a set with very much parts. I thought of the Unimog U400. But is there a webservice, where the sets are sorted by number of parts?

Comment: Related: http://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/170/132

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Brickset has a [data mining page](https://brickset.com/queries) which sorts sets by certain factors including new sets, unreleased sets, most minifigures in a set, best/worst price ratio and best British pound to American dollar exchange rates.

The sets with the most pieces can be found [here](http://brickset.com/sets/query-45). As of December 2018, the set with the most parts is the Star Wars [75192 Millennium Falcon](https://brickset.com/sets/75192-1/Millennium-Falcon), with 7541 pieces.