# The most amount of pieces [ever] per set

Tags: sets, records

Which set number had the most

- Standard LEGO elements to date?
- Technic LEGO elements to date?

Comment: Related: [What is the largest Lego kit commercially available](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/170/132)

Comment: @ambo100 I saw this, but my question is not the largest by dimension, but the largest by the number of pieces in a lego and a lego technic set.

Comment: Well the question Ambo mentioned talks about the set with most pieces, Taj Mahal. The most pieces for an actual Technic set is 42009: Mobile Crane MK II.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The largest LEGO set by piece count is :

[31203: World Map (2021)](https://brickset.com/sets/31203-1)

Piece count : 11695

Second:

[10294: RMS Titanic](https://brickset.com/sets/10294-1)

Piece count : 9090

Followed by :

[10276-1: Colosseum (2020)](https://brickset.com/sets/10276-1)

Piece count : 9035

---

Largest Techic set :

[42100-1: Liebherr R 9800 (2019)](https://brickset.com/sets/42100-1/Liebherr-9800)

Piece count : 4108

Second :

[42082-1: Rough Terrain Crane (2018)](https://brickset.com/sets/42082-1/Rough-Terrain-Crane)

Piece count : 4057